# Llamar al shell del subsistema Linux desde Jenkins en Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, jenkins

Creo una tarea en Jenkins (usando Windows 10) y en "Ejecutar un comando de Windows" pongo:

> bash
>
> python3 --versión

Y me aparece el siguiente error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\prueba ubuntu>bash
>
> "bash" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
> programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Desde la consola de Windows cmd funciona

Answer (score 0):

¿has probado con poner simplemente la parte de python3? El apartado "Ejecutar un comando de Windows" ya es una consola en sí, no necesitas invocar a bash para ello.

> python3 --version